# Automatically Register Class to the Window

Tags: javascript

I am wondering, is there a way to automatically register a class to the window? Right now to do so, I have to do `window.MyClass = MyClass` like this:

```
class MyClass {

}

window.MyClass = MyClass;
```

I would like the `window.MyClass = MyClass` to automatically happen, is there a way to do this?

Comment: Automatically in what way? You won't be able to just type `class MyClass { ... }` have it be global so you would require some kind of scaffolding to automatically handle the hookup. Are you looking for shorter scaffolding that what you have? Are you declaring multiple classes in one place that you'd like to be global? Would you be interested in using any code transformers such as Babel to automatically inject the `window.MyClass = MyClass` for you?

Comment: Basically I am making a framework, and it would be nice not to have to register the class every time I create a new class. So I have an HTML attribute that looks like this `component="MyClass"`, and then gets created like this `new window[name]()` where name equals `MyClass`. This doesn't work unless I have the register part, which I would like to happen automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this would be to create a function for registering a class. [Classes] have a `name` property which you can use for registering the name in the global space. This does require you to declare your classes inside of a function but without some kind of code transformation being done before the code hits the browser, it's about the best you can do.

```js
function register(c) {
  console.log('Registering ' + c.name);
  window[c.name] = c;
}

register(class ClassA {
  constructor() {
    console.log('Created ClassA');
  }
});

register(class ClassB {
  constructor() {
    console.log('Created ClassB');
  }
});

register(class ClassC {
  constructor() {
    console.log('Created ClassC');
  }
});

new ClassA();
new ClassB();
new ClassC();
```

Comment: I think this is a much more elegant way to handle this! Thank you!